# Cannot tap red minus delete button in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am able to make the red minus button appear on each of my UITableViewCells with the following calls:

```
[self.tableview setEditing:YES];
```

and

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Now, the red minus buttons appear to the left of the UITableViewCells. However, I can't interact with them via a simple tap (only if I swipe from the red minus to the right).

I want the "Delete" button to appear when I **tap** on the "Red Minus" button, not just when I **swipe**.

Why isn't my "Red Minus" button listening to a tap gesture?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of what my UITableViewCells look like:

[image: Edit mode on my UITableViewCells]

Comment: How do you create and add subviews to your cells? And are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: They're actually all dropped in through the storyboard. I just called HIDE on certain subviews when I enter editing mode (e.g. there's an icon that appears where the "Red Minus" button is in the SS above, I hide that and then show the "Red Minus" button by calling setEditing). And no, I'm using a ViewController like so: @interface AHBBrowseContactsViewController : AHBViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,AHBSelectorPickleDelegate>

Comment: You use 'hidden' to hide or 'alpha'?

Comment: Hidden. For example:  
 self.shareButton.hidden = YES;
 self.callButton.hidden = YES;
 self.customPublicSwitch.hidden = NO;

Comment: Also, just realized that my table is editable even when I comment out the "setEditing" line...is that normal?

Comment: Nope. Does the delete button work when you swipe?

Comment: Just fixed that problem. The delete button always works fine...it's just the only way I can reveal it right now is to swipe from the "Red Minus" button and to the right. So strange...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a gesture recognizer getting in the way (dismisses the keyboard when you click outside of the searchbar).

once I removed that everything worked great!

Comment: I believe I figured that out...and also you don't have to remove it. You just set the cancelsTouchesInView flag to NO

Comment: Tommy's fix is great - fixes the touch box of the deletion as well as keeping the tap gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the commitEditingStyle tableViewDelegate method?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is implemented as well. The bigger problem is getting the "Delete" button to show up by just tapping on the "Red Minus" button...

Comment: hmm thats weird. Pretty sure that functionality is built in. Did you put other gesture recognizers on the tableView?

Comment: No other gesture recognizers. However, it is a pretty complicated UITableViewCell. Each cell contains a UISwitch, a reorder slider, and a UILabel. Those are on the right side. The red minus button is on the left

Comment: just added a screenshot to the original question.